# How do I deploy images from ECR to EKS on a different AWS account using CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am working on a CodePipeline - building code, creating images, pushing to ECR, and then deploying to multiple EKS. This is working well so far. Now we need to deploy the images to another EKS set up in a different AWS account. Not sure how we may do it.

To illustrate better, we have CodeCommit, CodeBuild, CodePipeline, ECR all in one account (say Account-A) and the EKS is in another account (Account-B)

We read this: [Use ECR images in EKS from another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301924/use-ecr-images-in-eks-from-another-account)

We figured out the AWS IAM requirements for cross-account and that is in progress. But how to deploy (we are using KubeCtl from a CodeBuild in Account-A) from the pipeline to the EKS on Account-B is what we are facing challenges on.

Any pointer that helps us? We are fairly beginners in this area.